# Surjectivity of the Fourier Transform on Schwartz Space

Tags: fourier-analysis

I understand that, for $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$ (the Schwartz space) the transform
\begin{equation} \tag1
Tf(\xi) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{i\xi x}f(x) \,dx
\end{equation}

defines a left inverse for the Fourier Transform
\begin{equation}
f(x) \mapsto \mathcal{F}(\xi) = \hat{f}(\xi) = (2\pi)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-i\xi x} f(x) \, dx
\end{equation}

Now I need to show that it is a right inverse, or (equivalently) that $\mathcal{F}$ is surjective.

Here is where I am struggeling to proceed. The proof that I am currently reading states that  surjectivity follows from the fact that $(1)$ maps $f(x)$ to $\hat{f}(-\xi)$, but why does this mean that $\mathcal{F}$ is surjective?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Your fact implies applying the transform 4 times returns the original function. So the inverse transform is the same as applying the transform 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform converts differentiation into multiplication by polynomials.  The Schwartz functions die at $\infty$ despite multiplication by polynomials and iterated differentation.

They are topologized as a locally convex spaces by norms that multiply by polynomials and differentiate. The result is that the Fourier transform sends them homeomorphically onto themselves.